Repenting cannot forgive certain sin?
Isn’t it true that King David suffered a lot! Losing a child, his sons rebelling against him, he speak of having a lot of joint pain and being sick. Even such a righteous person who was so close to God that he wrote the palms suffered. Suffering is part of cleaning us. Some sins can be forgiven without any suffering and some cannot.

Is that a statement or a question?

What exactly are you asking? And how are the title and body related?
